# How to find intersection points of $n$ $n$-spheres reliably and efficiently when $n$ is large

Tags: equation-solving, computational-geometry

I have positions and radii of $n$ $n$-dimensional hyperspheres and want to find their intersection points efficiently. A very-straight-forward solution seems quite reliable:

```
Timing@With[{d = 50},
  With[{
    p = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, d],
    s = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {d, d}]},
   Sort[EuclideanDistance[p, #] & /@
     (Array[x, d] /.
       Quiet@Solve[
         Element[Array[x, d], Sphere[#, EuclideanDistance[p, #]]] & /@ s,
         Array[x, d]])]]]

{69.002, {4.84698*10^-14, 0.858948}}
```

The problem here is that 50-dimensional solution already takes about 70 seconds on my system, and I'd want to find solutions when $n \gg 100$. `FindMinimum` or `NMinimize` of sums of squares of sphere surface distances might work to an extent, but these find only one of the solutions. Are there good alternatives to the straight-forward `Solve`?

Comment: Are you looking for all-pairs solutions? Also what exactly should a solution contain? Orthogonal vector defining the hyperplane of intersection plus center and radius of the intersecting hypercircle?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I'm honestly wondering if I'm naive, but don't almost all intersections of $n$ $n$-spheres result at most two point solutions? In practice I'm looking for those, not pairwise hypercircles (if I stated my intent incompletely).

Comment: I misunderstood; I thought you were seeking pairwise sphere intersection sets. You are quite correct, and apologies for the noise.

Comment: Also: Now that I actually understand the question, the linear algebra approach is the method of choice for this.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau No problem! I also thought that linear algebra solution *should* be the way to go, but frankly, as this is not what I do for a living I just felt that somebody here probably can quickly come about with a  highly performing alternative to the trivial problem statement in Wolfram Language. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `pts` is a $d \times d$ matrix whose rows are the $d$ center points, and `rs` is a list of $d$ positive numbers containing the radii, then this will calculate the two intersection points (assuming they intersect at all...):

```
find[pts_,rs_]:=With[{A=MapThread[hyperplane[First[pts],First[rs],#1,#2]&,{Rest[pts],Rest[rs]}]},
    Module[{s},With[{c=LinearSolve[A[[;;,1]],A[[;;,2]]]+s*First[NullSpace[A[[;;,1]]]]},
        c/.Solve[(c-First[pts]).(c-First[pts])==First[rs]^2,s]]]];
hyperplane[pA_,rA_,pB_,rB_]:={pB-pA,(rA^2-Dot[pA,pA]-rB^2+Dot[pB,pB])/2};
```

Example

```
(* generate spheres *)
d=500;
SeedRandom[1];
p0=RandomReal[{-1,1},{d}];
pts=RandomReal[{-1,1},{d,d}];
rs=Map[Norm[#-p0]&,pts];

(* example *)
AbsoluteTiming[Map[Norm[#-p0]&,find[pts,rs]]]
(* {0.148522,{6.9176*10^-12,0.201555}} *)
```

**Comment:** Given two spheres $A$ and $B$ with centers $p_A$, $p_B$ and radii $r_A$, $r_B$ then a point $x$ lies on both spheres if
$$
\|x-p_A\|^2 = r_A^2
\qquad
\|x-p_B\|^2 = r_B^2
$$
Subtracting the two equations gives the linear equation
$$
x \cdot (p_B-p_A) = (r_A^2 - \|p_A\|^2 - r_B^2 + \|p_B\|^2)/2
$$
as a necessary condition where the dot means the `Dot`-product. So this restricts $x$ to a hyperplane. The code above computes the equations for $d-1$ such hyperplanes (intersection of sphere 1 with each of the $d-1$ other spheres), then computes their intersection which generically is a line (see LinearSolve and NullSpace), then computes those two points on the line that lie on sphere 1 (using Solve).

Answer (score 2):

Well, speeding it up significantly (but not as much as @user293787...) was easier than I thought:

```
Timing@With[{d = 500},
  With[{
    p = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, d],
    s = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {d, d}]},
   Sort[EuclideanDistance[p, #] & /@
     ({#, 2 RegionNearest[
             Hyperplane[Cross @@ (# - First@s & /@ Rest@s), First@s], #] - #} &@
       (Array[x, d] /.
         Last@FindMinimum[
           Sum[
            ((SquaredEuclideanDistance[Array[x, d], c] /. Abs -> Identity) -
               SquaredEuclideanDistance[p, c])^2, {c, s}],
           Array[x, d], MaxIterations -> 1000]))]]]

(* {54.6429, {7.00921*10^-10, 0.0262783}} *)
```

So, with `FindMinimum` and increased `MaxIterations` one can typically accomplish meaningful results for 500-dimensional case in comparable time to the original 50-dimension case. The original example takes now about 0.1 seconds instead of over a minute.

The second point is found simply by projecting the found solution through the hyperplane spanned by the centres of spheres to the opposite side of the hyperplane.